# Entity Framework - Includes for inherited types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

In my data model, I have a base class `Case` for which there can be a few different types: an `Investigation`, `DisciplinaryAction`, etc.  These all inherit from `Case`.  This is how I've modeled it in Entity Framework.

```
public abstract class Case : BaseEntity
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public int CaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public CaseType CaseType { get; set; }
}

public class Investigation : Case
{
}
```

For the inherited classes, `CaseId` is the primary key and foreign key. I have a single `DbSet` for `Cases`.  When I need to explicitly access one of the inherited types, I use `context.Cases.OfType<Investigation>()`.  All this is working fine.

In my `CaseRepository`, I have a method to get a case by ID:

```
public Case GetById(int id)
{
    var oversightCase = context.Cases
        .Include(p => p.Owner)
        .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
        .Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);
}
```

My question is that, for one of the inherited types, I want to include another navigation property.  Is there a way to access inherited types generically and include properties that not all inherited types have in a manner that's less disgusting than this:

```
public Case GetById(int id)
{
    var oversightCase = context.Cases
        .Include(p => p.Owner)
        .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
        .Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
        .Include(p => p.LinkedObjects)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);
    if (oversightCase != null && oversightCase is Investigation)
    {
        oversightCase = context.Cases.OfType<Investigation>()
            .Include(p => p.Owner)
            .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
            .Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
            .Include(p => p.LinkedObjects)
            .Include(p => p.Investigatee)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);
    }
    return oversightCase;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to do two requests when the `case id` is related to `Investigation`. Doing it like you write it, is not the correct way. 
Because if the `id` is related to an `Investigation` you are doing two big requests to your database with **each one doing the same first four join queries**.

The second request (in your `if` statement block) is just an extension of your first request because they share this code:

```
.Include(p => p.Owner)
.Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
.Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
.Include(p => p.LinkedObjects)
```

To avoid performance issue in the future:

First create a generic method like the code below where T must be a subclass of `Case`:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetCaseCommonData<T>()
    where T : Case
{
    return context.Cases.OfType<T>
        .Include(p => p.Owner)
        .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
        .Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
        .Include(p => p.LinkedObjects);
}
```

Second, use the generic method like this:

```
public Case GetById(int id)
{
    Case oversightCase;
    if (context.Cases.OfType<Investigation>().Any(f => f.CaseId == id))
    {
        oversightCase = GetCaseCommonData<Investigation>()
            .Include(p => p.Investigatee)
            .SingleOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);
    }
    else
    {
        oversightCase = GetCaseCommonData<Case>()
            .SingleOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);
    }
    return oversightCase;
}
```

With my solution, the `include` like the ocde below are executed once:

```
.Include(p => p.Owner)
.Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
.Include(p => p.ModifiedBy)
.Include(p => p.LinkedObjects);
```

By refactoring your code like I do, the query to check if a case id is an `Investigation` type is more efficient than the code you write for the same purpose:

```
context.Cases.OfType<Investigation>().Any(f => f.CaseId == id)
```

Comment: Thanks.  A few issues w/ your code. When calling `GetCaseCommonData` in `GetById()`, you have to define the generic `T`, no?  Assuming so, how can I cast the `IQuerable` such that I can include `Investigatee` because this doesn't work: `oversightCase = getCaseData<Investigation>().Include(p => p.Investigatee).FirstOrDefault(f => f.CaseId == id);`.

Comment: I edited my code. You don't need to use T parameter just replace with the correct type.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The correct signature is `public IQueryable<T> GetCaseCommonData<T>()` Notice the `IQueryable<T>` and not `IQueryable<Case>`